# Apache rewrite condition not matched

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm being crazy with that stuff:

Here is my .htaccess content :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And when i go on : http://mydomain.com

Here is what i got in rewrite log :

```
RewriteCond: input='www.mydomain.com' pattern='!^www\.' => not-matched
```

So the input should be mydomain.com and the condition should match but nope...

When i try to  specify the domain name in  the .htaccess i get infinite loops...

I'll try to keep calm and take a depp breath by hoping somebody can help me..

Thanks guys !

Comment: When you request only `mydomain.com`, your rewriting works, and you are redirected to `www.mydomain.com`. That causes another request – and for this request, of course the pattern does not match …

Comment: Isn't the `RewriteCond` log from the second run, after first rewrite occurred?

Comment: Also make sure to test this in a different browser.

Comment: There is no first rewrite. When i type mydomain.com, i stay on mydomain.com and still the log show an www.mydomain.com input. Same on all browers... i'm start thinking that i got a misfunction on dns zone. Need to check it...

Comment: Your rule is correct as you can see on the rewrite log when it hits www.domain it gives you a "not-matched" which means it will not execute the rewrite rule, unless you have other rules that may be doing something to redirect back or your own site have some header or redirect to the non-www version it should work just fine. Maybe you're cached from previous attempts so you should try a different browser just to see if the rule is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i fixed the problemS, this this the list of all things i needed to do, maybe someone will get the same problem.

First, i need to activate the rewrite mod of apache with this cmd :

```
a2enmode rewrite
```

Then you need to go to the httpd.conf or apache2.conf and set the two first :

```
AllowOverride None
```

into

```
AllowOverride All
```

if you have define some specific domain redirection, only do it in the domain conf file.

Now you can check if your .htaccess is red. Wrote anything like XXXX and it should return you an internal 500 error. If it's not, rewrite and so .htaccess is not activate.

And now, that's where i was blocked, you need to check your dns redirection.

That was my previous configuration:

```
www.mydomain.com    typeA  XXX.MY.IP.XXX
.mydomain.com       typeA  www.mydomain.com
```

So in fact, and even if the url adress still show http://mydomain.com, apache thought it came from www.mydomain.com so the .htaccess make no move...

I set it up like that :

```
www.mydomain.com    typeA  XXX.MY.IP.XXX
.mydomain.com       typeA  XXX.MY.IP.XXX
```

And ad into my apache configuration domain

```
ServerName www.tagmydiscount.com
ServerAlias tagmydiscount.com
```

And now, it's finally working like a charm. Hope it'll help some of you.